# Nautilus problem (Window-manager wrong name to folder)

Tags: unity, window-manager, filemanager

My distribution is: Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
Desktop Environment = Unity

I have a problem with Nautilus. I explain you.
I had it uninstalled to install Nemo. Now I have reinstalled it but, after a while when I open a folder on the Desktop, Nautilus opens another process with a folder header that has nothing to do with it. To understand it better I made a screen recorder that shows the problem. (https://streamable.com/b17ru)

Can anyone give me a hand to restore Nautilus properly?

Comment: strange bug I've never seen before

Comment: me neither. What can I do?

I've tried to unistall it, install it again but nothing.

Comment: Try remove config `rm -Rf ~/.config/nautilus/` and then restart nautilus using `nautilus -q`. If that does not help, I'm sorry I don't know.

Comment: maybe I've deleted some config. this is the output of 'nautilus -q':


(nautilus:20366): Gtk-WARNING **: Failed to register client: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files
Initializing nautilus-image-converter extension

(nautilus:20366): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: <broken file>:1:0: Failed to import: The resource at '/org/gnome/libgd/tagged-entry/default.css' does not exist

** (nautilus:20366): CRITICAL **: Another desktop manager in use; desktop window won't be created

Comment: Try, `rm -rf $HOME/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/*`

Comment: Unpin the files icon on the very left. Then pin the files icon that is created when you launch nautilus. If this works, next time, no duplicate icon should be created.